# Google Map Animate ImageMapType Overlay

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been reading and researching how to animate overlays. I Haven't found anything related to what I am looking for. Mostly it was related to markers. I have an overlay I apply like this and it works great.

```js
tileNEX = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
        return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime();
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    opacity: 0.60,
    name: 'NEXRAD',
    isPng: true
});
```

The source for the data also offers 10 other past images. So I would like to create an animated loop with those feeds. Is this option available in V3 as I have read some conflicts with doing this. I mean it must be possible because I have seen others with it. How would I go about loading the multiple layers then animating them?

-Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I hope this helps someone else looking for the same thing. This probably isn't the most elegant solution but it got the task done. I simply map over the predefined image urls creating my ImageMapTypes and then pass that into an animation loop which checks to see if there is a layer on the map, clears if it there is and then sets the new layer based on a loop count. Hope this helps.

```
var map;
// Weather tile url from Iowa Environmental Mesonet (IEM): http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/ogc/
var urlTemplate = 'http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-{timestamp}/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png';
// The time stamps values for the IEM service for the last 50 minutes broken up into 5 minute increments.
var timestamps = ['900913-m50m', '900913-m45m', '900913-m40m', '900913-m35m', '900913-m30m', '900913-m25m', '900913-m20m', '900913-m15m', '900913-m10m', '900913-m05m', '900913'];

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 38.0781, lng: -97.7030},
    zoom: 5
  });

  let tileSources = timestamps.map((timestamp) => {
    return new google.maps.ImageMapType({
      getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
          const { x, y} = tile;
          return `https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-${timestamp}/${zoom}/${x}/${y}.png?`+ (new Date()).getTime();
      },
      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
      opacity:0.60,
      name : 'NEXRAD',
      isPng: true
    });
  });

  startAnimation(map, tileSources);
}

function startAnimation(map, layers) {
  // create empty overlay entry
  map.overlayMapTypes.push(null);
  var count = 0;
  window.setInterval(() => {
    if(map.overlayMapTypes.getLength() > 0)
      map.overlayMapTypes.clear();

    map.overlayMapTypes.setAt("0",layers[count]);
    count = (count + 1) % layers.length;          
  },800);
}
```

Comment: Can we get Radar data from other parts of the world using this api? @Dan

Comment: @swifty I would say take a look at the Iowa State University (Iowa Enviromental Mesonet) (https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu) website because the do offer other climate data. I was using the NEXRAD data which looks like it is only radar for U.S., Alaska, Hawaii, U.S. territories, and U.S. military bases.